# How do I access request metadata for a java grpc service I am defining?

Tags: java, python, request, metadata, grpc

For some background, I am attempting to use [grpc auth](http://www.grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html#authenticate-with-google-4) in order to provide security for some services I am defining.

Let's see if I can ask this is a way that makes sense. For my python code, it was pretty easy to implement the server side code.

```
class TestServiceServer(service_pb2.TestServiceServer):

    def TestHello(self, request, context):

        ## credential metadata for the incoming request
        metadata = context.invocation_metadata()

        ## authenticate the user using the metadata
```

So, as you can tell, I am able to get the metadata from "context" quite easily. What is harder for me is to do the same thing in java.

```
public class TestImpl extends TestServiceGrpc.TestServiceImplBase {

    @Override
    public void testHello(TestRequest req, StreamObserver<TestResponse> responseObserver) {

        // How do I get access to similar request metadata here?

        // from the parameter positions, it looks like it should be
        // "responseObserver" but that doesn't seem similar to "context"

    }

}
```

I'll admit my problem comes from a few directions.

1) I am not well versed in Java

2) I heavily used python's "pdb" in order to debug the classes and see what methods are available to me. I don't know of/am not proficient at a similar tool for java.

3) The documentation seems rather sparse at this point. It shows you how to set up an ssl connection on the server side, but I can't find an example of the server taking a look at request metadata, as I have shown in python.

Could someone please give me an idea of how to do this, or perhaps show me a useful debugging tool for java in the same vein of python's pdb?

EDIT/ANSWER :

I needed to first write a definition implementing the interface ServerInterceptor.

```
private class TestInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
    ....
```

Then, before actually binding my service and building my server, I needed to do this.

```
TestImpl service = new TestImpl();
ServerServiceDefinition intercepted = ServerInterceptors.intercept(service, new TestInterceptor());
```

Now I was able to create the server.

```
server = NettyServerBuilder.forPort(port)

    // enable tls
    .useTransportSecurity(
        new File(serverCert),
        new File(serverKey)
    )
    .addService(
        intercepted  // had been "new TestImpl()"
    )
    .build();

server.start();
```

This allowed my ServerInterceptor to actually be called when I fired off a client side request.

[This link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/16c07ba434787f68e256fc50cece1425f421b03e/core/src/test/java/io/grpc/ServerInterceptorsTest.java) was quite helpful in figuring this out.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a `ServerInterceptor` and then propagate the identity via `Context`. This allows you to have a central policy for authentication.

The interceptor can retrieve the identity from `Metadata headers`. It *should then validate* the identity. The validated identity can then be communicated to the application (i.e., `testHello`) via `io.grpc.Context`:

```
/** Interceptor that validates user's identity. */
class MyAuthInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
  public static final Context.Key<Object> USER_IDENTITY
      = Context.key("identity"); // "identity" is just for debugging

  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
      Metadata headers,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    // You need to implement validateIdentity
    Object identity = validateIdentity(headers);
    if (identity == null) { // this is optional, depending on your needs
      // Assume user not authenticated
      call.close(Status.UNAUTENTICATED.withDescription("some more info"),
                 new Metadata());
      return new ServerCall.Listener() {};
    }
    Context context = Context.current().withValue(USER_IDENTITY, identity);
    return Contexts.interceptCall(context, call, headers, next);
  }
}

public class TestImpl extends TestServiceGrpc.TestServiceImplBase {
  @Override
  public void testHello(TestRequest req, StreamObserver<TestResponse> responseObserver) {
    // Access to identity.
    Object identity = MyAuthInterceptor.USER_IDENTITY.get();
    ...
  }
}

// Need to use ServerInterceptors to enable the interceptor
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(PORT)
    .addService(ServerInterceptors.intercept(new TestImpl(),
        new MyAuthInterceptor()))
    .build()
    .start();
```

Comment: Where is this 'interceptCall' method used?

Comment: Also, assuming that you mean my class needs to implement the interface "ServerInterceptor" (please remember java is not my forte), I had to make the ServerCall method public for it to even compile.

Comment: "interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT>, Metadata, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT>)' in 'getapi.example.TestServer' clashes with 'interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT>, Metadata, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT>)' in 'io.grpc.ServerInterceptor'; attempting to assign weaker access privileges ('package-private'); was 'public'"

Comment: Ok, this basically led me to the light. There was a little more that I needed to do.

I'll edit my question to provide the missing pieces.

Comment: I know I already accepted the answer here, but do you think you could explain what 

"Object identity = MyAuthInterceptor.USER_IDENTITY.get();"

does?

Comment: That's the only part that I don't understand. It seems to be not really serving any purpose in my code.

Comment: If you only want an authenticated user, then it serves no purpose. This is normal when you just want a login for billing. Often though you want to do _something_ with the user identity. Like check authorization or give each user their own namespace of objects. That's when you would use USER_IDENTITY.get().

Comment: So more for authorization, rather than authentication?

Comment: Yes, more of authorization, but also for accessing account-specific resources. Consider an email API listing emails in the inbox; it is implicitly scoped to the user. That's very similar to authz, but not equivalent.