# gRPC Java - Storing State variables (For user authentication)

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I am using gRPC in a SpringBoot (and SpringSecurity) environment and I use a `ServerInterceptor` to authenticate users when they connect. I store the authentication result in Spring's `SecurityContextHolder`. ([Followed this](https://eng.revinate.com/2017/11/07/grpc-spring-security.html))

```
private final AuthenticationManager manager;

@Autowired
public AuthenticatorInterceptor(final AuthenticationManager manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
}

@Override
public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall,
                                                             Metadata metadata, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {
    logger.info("Authorizing user information for GRPC access");

    final String authHeader = nullToEmpty(metadata.get(Metadata.Key.of("authorization", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER)));
    if (!authHeader.startsWith("Basic ")) {
        logger.error("No Authentication Info found");
        throw Status.PERMISSION_DENIED.withDescription("No Authentication Info found").asRuntimeException();
    }

    try {
        final String[] tokens = decodeBasicAuth(authHeader);
        final String userName = tokens[0];

        if (authenticationIsRequired(userName)) {
            final Authentication pending = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, tokens[1]);
            final Authentication result = manager.authenticate(pending);
            logger.info("Authentication success for this user");

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
        }
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        logger.error("Authentication failed - No GRPC Access", e);
        throw Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription(e.getMessage()).withCause(e).asRuntimeException();
    }

    return serverCallHandler.startCall(serverCall, metadata);
}
```

But the problem is that the authentication is leaked and shared among the clients. For example, if Client A connects and authenticates and then when another client B connects, the client B is already authenticated with Client A's credentials.

I guess this is because the default `SecurityContext` of `SecurityContextHolder` uses a `ThreadLocal` to store the auth information and gRPC is likely reusing threads for different connections.

**Where should I store the auth information?** I saw the `Context` class ([gRPC context](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Context.html)), but couldn't understand (and couldn't find any resource) how to correctly implement my required functionality.

*PS: I used [SpringBoot gRPC Starter](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter) to configure the gRPC server and its interceptors.*

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40113309/4690866