# Spring Boot GRPC: ServerIntereceptor to read data in the request, and set it in the response

Tags: multithreading, grpc, interceptor, thread-local, grpc-java

There is a field called "metadata" (not to be confused with GRPC metadata) that is present in every request proto that comes to the GRPC service:

```
message MyRequest {
  RequestResponseMetadata metadata = 1;
  ...
}
```

And the same field is also present in all responses:

```
message MyResponse {
  RequestResponseMetadata metadata = 1;
  ...
}
```

I am trying to write a `ServerInterceptor` (or something else, if it works) to read the "metadata" field from the request, keep it somewhere, and then set it in the response once done processing the request.

**Attempt 1: ThreadLocal**

```
public class ServerInterceptor implements io.grpc.ServerInterceptor {

  private ThreadLocal<RequestResponseMetadata> metadataThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
      final Metadata requestHeaders,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    return new SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(
        next.startCall(
            new SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {
              @Override
              public void sendMessage(RespT message) {
                super.sendMessage(
                    (RespT)
                        MetadataUtils.setMetadata(
                            (GeneratedMessageV3) message, metadataThreadLocal.get()));
                metadataThreadLocal.remove();
              }
            },
            requestHeaders)) {
      @Override
      public void onMessage(ReqT request) {
        // todo nava see if ReqT can extend GenericV3Message
        var metadata = MetadataUtils.getMetadata((GeneratedMessageV3) request);
        metadataThreadLocal.set(metadata);
        super.onMessage(request);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I tried to use `ThreadLocal`, to later [realise](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1949) that `sendMessage` and `onMessage` need not necessary to be on the same thread.

**Attempt 2: GRPC Context**

```
public class ServerInterceptor implements io.grpc.ServerInterceptor {

  public static final Context.Key<RequestResponseMetadata> METADATA_KEY = Context.key("metadata");

  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
      final Metadata requestHeaders,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    return new SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(
        next.startCall(
            new SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {
              @Override
              public void sendMessage(RespT message) {
                super.sendMessage(
                    (RespT)
                        MetadataUtils.setMetadata(
                            (GeneratedMessageV3) message, METADATA_KEY.get()));
              }
            },
            requestHeaders)) {
      @Override
      public void onMessage(ReqT request) {
        var metadata = MetadataUtils.getMetadata((GeneratedMessageV3) request);
        var newContext = Context.current().withValue(METADATA_KEY, metadata);
        oldContext = newContext.attach();
        super.onMessage(request);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I am planning to detach the context in a `onComplete()`, but before it reaches there itself, `METADATA_KEY.get()` in `sendMessage` returns `null`, while I was expecting it to return the data.

Even before hitting the `sendMessage()` function, I get this in the console, indicating that I am doing something wrong:

```
3289640 [grpc-default-executor-0] ERROR i.g.ThreadLocalContextStorage - Context was not attached when detaching
java.lang.Throwable: null
    at io.grpc.ThreadLocalContextStorage.detach(ThreadLocalContextStorage.java:48)
    at io.grpc.Context.detach(Context.java:421)
    at io.grpc.Context$CancellableContext.detach(Context.java:761)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:39)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

How do I read data when a request is received, store it somewhere and use it when the response is send back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access request metadata for a java grpc service I am defining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112374/how-do-i-access-request-metadata-for-a-java-grpc-service-i-am-defining)

Comment: @EricAnderson sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question to explain it a bit more.

Comment: Follow the other answer. Use Contexts.interceptCall(). Context attach/detach follows the call stack, so you can't attach it without having a detach in the same method. In your case you can put something mutable (e.g., AtomicReference, SettableFuture, custom object) in the Context during the initial interceptCall() and then mutate that object within onMessage().

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Metadata](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Metadata.html) to pass values from the request to the response:

```java
public class MetadataServerInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    public static final Metadata.Key<byte[]> METADATA_KEY = Metadata.Key.of("metadata-bin", Metadata.BINARY_BYTE_MARSHALLER);

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
        var serverCall = new ForwardingServerCall.SimpleForwardingServerCall<>(call) {
            @Override
            public void sendMessage(RespT message) {
                byte[] metadata = headers.get(METADATA_KEY);
                message = (RespT) MetadataUtils.setMetadata((GeneratedMessageV3) message, metadata);
                super.sendMessage(message);
            }
        };
        ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> listenerWithContext = Contexts.interceptCall(Context.current(), serverCall, headers, next);
        return new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<>(listenerWithContext) {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(ReqT message) {
                byte[] metadata = MetadataUtils.getMetadata((GeneratedMessageV3) message);
                headers.put(METADATA_KEY, metadata);
                super.onMessage(message);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Note:** Since it is not possible to put the instance of `RequestResponseMetadata` in the metadata (at least without implementing a custom marshaller), you can save it there as a byte array. You can use `toByteArray()` on your `RequestResponseMetadata` object to get `byte[]` and  `RequestResponseMetadata.#parseFrom(byte[])` to get the object from `byte[]`.